# Which way might commercial fusion power affect the earth's energy balance?

Tags: earth, estimation, power, fusion, climate-science

The ITER fusion-energy project might prove the feasibility of commercial fusion-energy generation by mid-century.

This would be a comparatively clean method of energy generation, and subject to affordability, can be expected to replace any remaining fossil fuel generation in what are currently developing countries, as a back up or co-generation method to renewables.

However, in the effort to raise living standards worldwide, as the human population is likely still approaching its peak, the potential demand for electrical energy worldwide is likely to be considerably greater than even the present level.

My question is: can we expect the overall release of the thermal energy resulting from a much higher energy demand worldwide to still facilitate a net reduction to global warming, or might it result in a net increase?

I don't have the data to propose a meaningful estimate/solution to this question, but others might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about anthropogenic heat flux aka waste heat relative to anthropogenic global warming.

According to Mark Flanner *["Integrating anthropogenic heat flux with global climate models" 2009](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2008GL036465)* -

`Although AHF exceeds 100 W m−2 in urban centers [Oke, 1988; Ichinose et al., 1999] and is treated in some urban- and meso-scale models [e.g., Kimura and Takahashi, 1991; Grimmond and Oke, 1991; Fan and Sailor, 2005; Dandou et al., 2005; Makar et al., 2006], it is neglected in current global climate models (GCMs), likely because its global average is only ∼1% of greenhouse gas forcing.`

The heat gained by enhanced greenhouse from fossil fuel burning far exceeds the heat introduced into the climate system by coal, gas, oil and nuclear. Wind and solar energy production does not introduce energy that would otherwise not be there.

Producing that same amount of heat by fusion energy in place of fossil fuel burning will result in a large *decrease* in global warming. Should use of fusion energy grow 100x of current energy use it would (roughly) equal the warming potential of recent fossil fuel use.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to note is that the total input--output for the energy movements includes the total sunlight falling on Earth, and this is much more than human energy use into the forseeable future. Human impact on climate and warming is mainly by affecting the way solar energy is reflected or retained, rather than by directly converting stored chemical or nuclear energy into heat.

So, the answer to your question is that if a power station converts a lot of nuclear energy into work and thus eventually into heat, but does so without creating greenhouse gases, then overall it tends to mitigate not increase global warming. Ultimately though, as I understand it, the climate issues will require not just less carbon (and similar) output, but also carbon capture on a large scale. Planting forests is a good way to do that, but some more technical ways may also help, and they may require energy, so fusion could possibly help with that.

Having said all the above, I would not regard fusion as the main thing to rely on now. Solar methods are already a good bet. But the need is for better economic calculations and investment of resources. Up till now the cost-benefit analysis which is used to place a price on things like oil has tended to weight present happiness as of greater value than future pain, and the weights are, I think, off and need to be adjusted. This is a political not just a physics issue so I won't say more other than that sound basic physics will help people understand how to take such decisions.